# error: "fatal: I don't handle protocol ``git` when using bundle install

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I have the following line in my GemFile :

`gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'`

I get the following error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/rails/rails.git
fatal: I don't handle protocol ''git'
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'...
```

but when I run `gem install 'rails'` it works fine.

basically when running the clone command, bundler adds the single quotes around the git:// address which throws the error.

I am working on windows. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Cheers

Comment: The error of duplicate single quotes is real.
[See here](https://gist.github.com/1001422)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the issue with the newer version of the Bundler 1.0.14.

I needed to revert to 1.0.13 to make it work. They apparently had some issues dealing with escape characters in Windows.

See here > https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1212

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', :git => "https://github.com/rails/rails.git"
```

`git://` can sometimes be blocked by firewalls. Though in your case that's probably not the issue. Try double quotes instead.