# New Ruby on Rails developer needs help setting up a development environment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I've been experimenting with Rails a lot lately, and have made progress. I set up my environment on Windows 7 according to http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, and made sure it works with the example code. Now I want to run a project from Github that I downloaded, but doing a bundle install produced errors on my machine (specifically github erros). How close do I need to duplicate the original developers environment? Kind of confused about how portable these apps are across platforms/servers, etc.

Here are the specs on apps original development environment if it helps:
-Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3, and MySQL 5.1.
-Ubuntu 10.04,Nginx, postfix, other dependencies installed like Sphinx (full text search engine) and ImageMagic (auto resize images & thumbnails).

Here is the error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git
fatal: I don't handle protocol ''git'
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git' "C:/Ra
ilsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/will_paginate-6ad0773
80835d8b425f1d46ebc3ada46214e7bbb" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory C:/Sites/
plurplay has failed.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Rails apps are fairly platform independent, could you please post the errors you said you are receiving when running ```bundle install```?

Comment: Sure, that would help:
Fetching git://github.com/mislav/will_pageinate.git
Git error: command 'git clone 'git://github.com/mislav/will_pageinate.git' "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/will_paginate.....

Comment: Errr, please edit your post and use code formatting with full error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solution here, [error: "fatal: I don't handle protocol ``git` when using bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213600/error-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-git-when-using-bundle-install)

If you don't need will_paginate's repo `head` you can always change

```
gem 'will_paginate', :git => "git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git"
```

To just

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

Comment: Cool, I should have just Googled the error first but I didn't realize it was that common! Anyway, that took care of the the Git error, but now it moved on to a Sphinx error. Must be a bundler version problem as described in your link.